# Set visibility with a trigger

Tags: .net, wpf, triggers, visibility, storyboard

I just want to start an storyboard which makes an rectangle visible for 2 seconds when user pressed with left mouse button. But I could not solve how to get the visibility value.

```
<Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown"  >
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetName="RectFront" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.100" Value="1" />
                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0" /> <---   HOW to change this into Visibility Type?
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```xml
Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"
```

but in some cases the XAML parser can just convert a normal string like `Value="Hidden"` as well.

A problem here is though that to animate Visibility you cannot use a `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames`, it has to be an `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`.

If you want to animate visibility gradually you can use a `DoubleAnimation` (with or without keyframes) but you need to target the [`Opacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacity.aspx) instead.

Comment: thanks H.B for your quick answer. With the objectKeyFrames it works and also by using the static methode like you did the example. Great